# Track movement of data between two data sets (or matrices)

Tags: python, r, excel, vba

I have two data sets for example July and August data and each number means the number of orders placed.
I would like to compare the data between the two sets and find any differences between them. 
There can be three differences mainly
a)= order cancelled (number exists in left dataset and not in right)
b) = new order (number exists in right dataset but not in left)
c) = postponed order (number exists in both datasets (but the number in the right dataset exists at a later month M0)
d) = preponed (to simplify we will assume this does not occur)

```
     July                       August              
TypeM09 M10 M11 M12     TypeM09 M10 M11 M12
A   0   1   2   0       A   0   1   2   0
B   1   0   0   0       B   0   0   1   0
C   1   2   0   0       C   0   1   0   0
D   1   2   2   0       D   1   0   0   2
```

Note - in Type D above, the number 2 occurs twice on the left dataset in M10 and M11, and once on the right dataset in M12. Since the program is checking data from left to right, as soon as the program picks up that M10 (in left dataset) exists in M12 (in right dataset), hence the number in M11 (left dataset is in fact cancelled since there are no more ''free'' numbers for it to match to in the right dataset.

the program should read something like this

```
Type    M09                   M10                     M11            M12
A       -                     no change no change     -              -
B       postponement to M11   -                       -              -
C       postponement to M10   cancellation  -   -
D       no change             postponement to M11      cancellation  -
```

As an output I would like to achieve something like this:

```
Type    Detail          Previous month  New month
x       Postponement    M07             M11
x       Postponement    M08             M12
y       Cancellation    M08             -
z       New order       -               M12
```

Comment: Great formatting in your edid @Saeed, well done! (your profile says "Do It Right, Do It Fast, Do It Once.", and you've lived up to it.)

Comment: @user23456 D instead of  getting postponement to M11 should get postponement to M12 right?

Answer (score 0):

I still have few doubts so was able to generate intermediate output only..
please add little more explanation with desired output for the example mentioned with type A, B, C, D

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_2dlist_1 = [
    ['Type', 'M09' ,'M10', 'M11', 'M12'],
    ['A' ,  0 , 1 , 2 , 0] ,     
    ['B' ,  1 , 0 , 0 , 0] ,     
    ['C' ,  1 , 2 , 0 , 0] ,     
    ['D' ,  1 , 2 , 2 , 0] ]

data_2dlist_2 =[
['Type', 'M09' ,'M10', 'M11', 'M12'],
['A', 0,   1,   2,   0],
['B', 0,   0,   1,   0],
['C', 0,   1,   0,   0],
['D', 1,   0,   0,   2]]

output_2d = [['Type', 'M09' ,'M10', 'M11', 'M12']]
final_output_2d = [['Type','Detail','Previous month'  ,'New month']]


for d1, d2 in zip(data_2dlist_1[1:],data_2dlist_2[1:]):
    #print(d1,d2)
    output_2d.append([d1[0]]) #new_type row creation
    looked = defaultdict()

    for i in range(1,len(d1),1):

        if d1[i] == 0: 
            output_2d[-1].append('-')

        elif d1[i] == d2[i]:
            output_2d[-1].append('no change')

        elif d1[i] != 0: 
            start = i+1
            if d1[i] in looked:
                start = looked[d1[i]] + 1
            try:
                found_at = d2.index(d1[i],start)
                output_2d[-1].append('postponement to '+ str(data_2dlist_2[0][found_at]))
                looked[d1[i]] = found_at

            except ValueError: #not found 
                output_2d[-1].append('cancellation')

        elif d2[i] not in looked: #and d1[i] == 0
            output_2d[-1].append('new order')

print(output_2d)

'''       

[['Type', 'M09', 'M10', 'M11', 'M12'],
['A', '-', 'no change', 'no change', '-'],
['B', 'postponement to M11', '-', '-', '-'],
['C', 'postponement to M10', 'cancellation', '-', '-'],
['D', 'no change', 'postponement to M12', 'cancellation', '-']]

'''
```